# .NET MAUI, Flyout Menu is overlapping the Windows title bar

Tags: windows, maui

I have a .NET 8 MAUI Application (mainly for Windows and Mac) where the FlyoutBehavior is in locked mode. Unfortunately the flyout is overlapping everything, even the title bar  (the one with the symbols for minimize, maximize and close) of the application.

I attached an example with multiple colors that you can see what I mean.
I would like that the green area on top is just the title bar, not the Flyout Background Color like it is now
[Screenshot Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTFzD.png)

on Mac this works fine -> [Screenshot Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qiNM.jpg)

AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell x:Class="UPclient.AppShell"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UPclient"
   Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
   Shell.FlyoutBackgroundColor="Green"
          
   >
<!--Shell.FlyoutBackgroundColor="#203864"-->
<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <ContentView 
                 HeightRequest="200">
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
            <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                   Source="store.jpg"
                   Opacity="0.6" />
            <Label Text="Header"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentView>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>

<Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    <ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Footer"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
           
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</Shell.FlyoutFooter>

<Shell.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Title"
           TextColor="White"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Start"
           Padding="5,0,0,0"
           HeightRequest="50"               
           FontSize="Small" />
</Shell.TitleView>


<ShellContent Title="......
```

Is there anything I can do against it? I cannot find any clue.

Thanks
Michael

I mainly tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0
I was able to set all the colors, but I did not find any overlapping settings.

Comment: `I would like that the green area on top is just the title bar, not the Flyout Background Color like it is now` Do you want the green color to only show up on the toolbar?  Could you please post the code of `AppShell.xaml`?

Comment: I don't know exactly with you mean with "toolbar". It is the light-gray windows title bar (with the symbols for minimize, maximize and close) which is overlapped by the flyout. this does not look good. The same looks fine on mac. I will add all another screenshot and the code to the original post.

Comment: For this problem, you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).